# Why is java (32-bit) JDK installer not copying rt.jar file to JRE directory? (Windows 2008 R2 SP1)

Tags: installation, java

The system is using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Tomcat 5.5.28, and Java SE 6 Update 20 for both JDK and JRE.

I updated the system to the latest JDK update, Java SE 6 Update 27, and let it install using defaults; it created a new directory, jdk1.6.0_27, and overwrote the jre directory.  It asked to restart and then I noticed Tomcat would not start.  I ran the java -version from the jre directory and it outputted

*Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object*

I discovered the directory was missing the *rt.jar* file; I pasted it from the jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin directory and java -version worked and Tomcat started.  My question is why is this error occurring in the first place??? Is it the Java installer?

I ran the Java Automatic update feature (which only updates JRE, not JDK) and it worked without a hiccup.  So, why is the Java installer from Oracle.com not updating the JRE directory properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have seen this happen before.

Comment: Do you run an upgrade? It could be a bug in JRE installer then. Try to install a previous version and the upgrade it, when no Java app runs. If the issue persists, report a bug to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the case all Windows installers have this `obligatory` phrase:

> Please close all running programs before you continue with installation

I think something was holding the old rt.jar and installer has a bug that cannot cope with this condition.

Comment: There was no obligatory message displayed.  But what I did was stop the Tomcat service, install the update, and then restarted Tomcat successfully.  Again, the installer didn't give a message.  But like you said, the installer must have a bug that cannot cope with the rt.jar being employed by Tomcat.  However, the Automatic update (which is just for the jre, not jdk) has no problem with rt.jar.  I guess because it's designed for updating, whereas the installer is not specific to updating Java.  Thank you again.

Comment: @user717236.  Sorry, that message was really a joke.  It's a part of many installers, because Windows is notoriously overzealous with file locking, which, in some cases, may lead to corrupt installations (your case in point).  Good installers, though, should always check that they can lock all required files before hand and if they can't - fail gracefully.